# How to change index and transposing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm new in pandas and trying to do some converting on the dateframe but I reach closed path.

my data-frame is:

```
  entity_name  request_status  dcount
0  entity1          0           1
1  entity1          1           6
2  entity1          2          13
3  entity2          1           4
4  entity2          2           7
```

I need this dataframe  to be like the following:

```
index      0      1      2
entity1    1      6      13
entity2    0      4      7
```

as it shown I take the entity_name column as index without duplicates and the columns names from request_status column   and the value from dcount

so please any one can help me to do that ?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
a = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'dcount', index='entity_name', columns='request_status').fillna(0)
a = a.astype(int)
```

Comment: Unbelievable, many thanks it works fine and correct.

but I have a simple question the numbers are float can I make them integer in new df?

Answer (score 3):

Regular [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) works as well:

```
df.pivot(values='dcount', index='entity_name', columns='request_status').fillna(0).astype(int)
```